# How to import external jar and compile it in command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java eclipse. I am trying compile and execute a simple code.
I am facing the following exception:
package does not exist
I tried the following commands, but this didn't help so far-
1. javac -cp "path to jar" Stack.java
2. java Stack
The compiler says edu.princeton.cs.algs4 package doesn't exist!

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;
//import static java.lang.System.*;
public class Stack
{
    private Node first = null;
    private int length = 0;

    private class Node
    {
        String item;
        Node next;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void push(String A)
    {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = A;
        first.next = oldfirst;
        length++;
    }

    public String pop()
    {
        String out;
        out = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        length--;
        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Stack stackofstrings = new Stack();
        StdOut.print("before while loop");
        while(!stackofstrings.isEmpty())
        {
            StdOut.print("Inside loop");
            String s = StdIn.readString();
            if(s.equals("-"))
            {
                StdOut.print(stackofstrings.pop());
            }
            else
                stackofstrings.push(s);
        }`enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: On one hand you want to import a jar in Eclispe and on the other you want to compile using the command line. What is exactly your problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear!

Comment: I have imported the Jar file in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Now, when I want to compile the file Stack.java. It gets compiled. But

Comment: It's not a messenger tchat, please write a single comment ^^

Comment: when I try to execute, it shows me the following error -  package edu.princeton.cs.algs4 does not exist

Comment: Yes, sorry for multiple comments!

Comment: is there a way to attach project files ?

Comment: I still don't understand what's the point with Eclispe. You're running it using the command line, Eclipse won't do anything.
I would guess that you forgot to specify the classpath when running the `java` command

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you compile and execute the Java code from within Eclipse. If you are using the command then Eclipse is not involved.

Comment: @greg-449 , thank you for your responses!
You guys are correct! Thank you!

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel, thank you for your help!